# A fair dice is rolled until a 2 comes up. Given the first roll is not 2, what's the probability it'll take more than 3 rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Also,

if it takes an even amount of rolls, what's the probability of exactly 2 rolls?

I am completely lost so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose an event has probability $p$ of happening. On the first trial, there is a $$p$$ chance that it occurs. To happen for the first time on the second trial, it would have to fail once and then succeed (let $q=1-p$): $$qp$$

To happen for the first time on the third trial, it would fail twice (two q's) and then succeed: $$qqp=q^2p$$ In general, the probability of it happening for the first time on trial $n$ is $$q^{n-1}p$$

To find the probability that it takes more than three rolls, add the probabilities that it takes 0, 1, 2, or 3 rolls, and then take 1 minus that answer. Do the same to find the probability that the first roll is not a two, and divide those results to get the answer.

Given that it's even, you know that $$P(2|even)=\frac{P(2 and even)}{P(even)}=\frac{P(2)}{P(even)}$$

The probability that it is even is $$P(2)+P(4)+P(6)...=qp+q^3p+q^5p+...=pq(1+q^2+q^4+...)$$ Use the geometric series formula to find what this is equal to.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable with geometric distribution with parameter $p = \frac{1}{6}$:
$
  P[X = k]
= (1-p)^{k-1} p.
$
Then the probability you ask for is
\begin{align}
   P[X > 3 | X \neq 1]
&= \frac{P[X > 3]}{P[X \neq 1]} \\
&= \frac{1 - P[X=1] - P[X=2]-P[X=3]}{1 - P[X=1]} \\
&= \frac{1-(1-p)(p+p^2+p^3)}{1 - (1-p)p} 
\end{align}